# Array arrangement

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, multidimensional-array

Currently my array looks like:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'housetype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Test' (length=6)
      public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'info_block_list_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'housetype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Test' (length=6)
      public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'info_block_list_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      public 'housetype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Test' (length=6)
      public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'info_block_list_id' => string '3' (length=1)
```

Since only `info_block_list_id` changes I want to rearrange my array to look like so:

```
object(stdClass)[35]
  public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
  public 'housetype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'name' => string 'Test' (length=6)
  public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'info_block_list_id' => 
    array (size=3)
       0 => string '1' (length=1)
       1 => string '2' (length=1)
       2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried something to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: That's not an array of array but an array of objects. To merge them, means, change object structure (for info_block_list_id at least)

Comment: Why is this a problem for you? You just create a new object, adding the "static" properties and then an array with a single entry for each of those "info_block_list_id" values. _Just do it._

Comment: @DonCallisto, call it as you may, my question still stands

Comment: @arkascha, I would do it if I knew how so far I have an empty `foreach` statement with no idea what to put inside

Comment: OK, that's a start! Great! So you _did_ try. Then post your attempt so far, add the code to the question, and we will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a variable that holds a hash/key of the unique id and changes to the info_block_list_id property to an array:

```
$items =  [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (!isset($items[ $data->id ])) {
        $items[ $data->id ] = $item;
        $items[ $data->id ]->info_block_list_id = [];
    }
    $items[ $data->id ]->info_block_list_id[] = $item->info_block_list_id;
}

var_dump($items);
```

Comment: Error:  Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simple, if you say that every object is the same expect for the `info_block_list_id` property. So save the first object into a variable and use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get all `info_block_list_id` properties into an array, e.g.

```
$object = $yourArray[0];
$object->info_block_list_id = array_map(function($v){
    return $v->info_block_list_id;
}, $yourArray);
```

Comment: @Clayton It will work, probably not how OP wants it. But as I read the question and written in the answer, if only the `info_block_list_id` property is different it works.